# -webkit-tap-highlight-color is not working

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am trying to remove tap highlight color. But it is not working mobile. When i am trying to see using inspect element on pc it is also not showing.

My css is

```
button, button:hover, li:hover, a:hover , li , a , *:hover, *
{
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

is there any error on my css..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159729/how-can-i-get-webkit-tap-highlight-color-to-highlight-an-entire-div

Comment: yaa i have already seen that question

Comment: `:active` might help you.

Comment: outline:none already tried ...

Comment: I have found one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210481/disable-orange-outline-highlight-on-focus

Comment: What device are you testing it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use both:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

**OR**

```
* {
    -webkit-touch-callout:none;                /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;             /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); /* prevent tap highlight color / shadow */
    -webkit-user-select:none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
}
```

Comment: Doing all of these will hurt accessibility big time.

Answer (score 9):

I thought I'd add to the accepted answer...

Using `cursor: pointer` will also cause the tap highlight to persist (even after setting *-webkit-tap-highlight-color*). Make sure to remove it on the element or parent it's inheriting from.

Comment: I struggled a lot until finding your answer. But it's odd though that `cursor: pointer` doesn't interfere when `-webkit-user-select` is defined in the same declaration, or when defined directly inside the style attribute of a tag.

Comment: [UPDATE] I meant `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`. And now it's working even with `cursor: pointer`. I don't get it.

Comment: :( oh,, that's no fun. I wanted to provide PC users with pointer cursor for any interactive element, but avoiding unnecessary tap highlight on mobile...

Comment: you just saved my precious time, why would chrome do that to us? Chrome.. come on..

Answer (score 0):

adding `-webkit-user-select: none;` helps at times!!

Answer (score 0):

My divs appeared to get highlighted, even though I used the necessary CSS tags to remove the highlight color. This only happened in Android WebView API 26.

After a lot of tinkering, it turned out that this had nothing to do with the highlight color. The div's transparent background color was briefly rendered fully opaque as it started a transition. To fix this, I simply replaced this transparent color:

```
div.style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 255, .05)";
```

... with a similar opaque color:

```
div.style.background = "rgba(246, 246, 255, 1)";
```

Answer (score -1):

I injected this code into a `<style>` tag on `<header>` on a Muse website and worked perfectly for me:

```
   * {
        -webkit-touch-callout:none;               
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;          
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
        -webkit-user-select:none;                 
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, when answering here please consider adding explanation and in which way your solution helps fixing the problem, this helps to both OP and other people looking for similar problem.