# webkit-tap-highlight-color on pseudo after element

Tags: ios, css, webkit, pseudo-element

I am working with "after" pseudo elements' content-property to add divider between my footer-links.

```
.link::after {
    content: " | ";
}
```

On iOS the the whole element including it's after-pseudo-element gets highlighted. This behaviour is unwanted - I would like the after-content not to get highlighted when its parent element (the "real" element) is active.

[Here's a screenshot of an clicked link on an iOS device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cmz1.png)

Setting the tap-highlight-color-property separately for the after-element doesn't seem to have any effect.

[jsfiddle representing this problem](https://jsfiddle.net/odqcj6e8/4/)

Is there any css-way that can solve this problem or do I have to change the non-css code to make the divider not get highlighted?

Comment: problem solved wrapping the links, placing the divider-pseudo-element on the wrap's ... while keeping the tap-highlight-color on the link itself.
https://jsfiddle.net/odqcj6e8/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try using these two:

```
.link,
.link::after {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

A few more SO answers and links are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853238/webkit-tap-highlight-color-is-not-working).